# Bundling open source google fonts in a browser based desktop app

Tags: electron, webfonts

I'm looking to download and bundle open source fonts from https://fonts.google.com/ in a browser based desktop application (electron based). I'm struggling to figure out what (if any) restrictions exist when bundling something from google fonts in this scenario.

Is there an authoritative source on appropriate use of these fonts? I was not able to tell if this is appropriate use from the terms of service. Any advice on this or the appropriate place to post would be welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're in the clear to download the font packs and bundle them in your app.

Check out the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/fonts/faq) for google fonts. There are a few answer that definitely imply you're fine to take them and build them into your app.

However at the bottom of the FAQ they link you to the [license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) for the fonts, which is the creative commons license stating you are free to:

> Share — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format
>
> Adapt — remix, transform, and build upon the material
> for any purpose, even commercially.